# Insert Images from File to ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, image, simplecursoradapter

How can I add images from file not as a blob using SimpleCursorAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use a [viewbinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html), before binding each element of the list you will get a callback on

> setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)

Depending on the columnindex you can setImage and then return true for only this case. Rest all cases you will have to return false, so that the SimplecursorAdapter will fill with appropriate data